# SQL Server 2012: Query with variable returning zero rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This query is returning output in desired way when i hard code the value but when i use @PAYMENT_VOUCHER_NUMBER variable instead of hard coded data that is 'REVIEW_PAYMENT_VOUCHER_31' it does not return any row.

```
/* Not working */ 
DECLARE @PAYMENT_VOUCHER_NUMBER VARCHAR(15) = NULL;

Set @PAYMENT_VOUCHER_NUMBER ='REVIEW_PAYMENT_VOUCHER_31';

SELECT REF_NUM
    ,CASE 
        WHEN RW_PT_VOUCHER_NUMBER = @PAYMENT_VOUCHER_NUMBER
            THEN 1
        WHEN ML_PT_VOUCHER_NUMBER = @PAYMENT_VOUCHER_NUMBER
            THEN 2
        END FEE_TYPE
FROM PROC_FEES_PYMTS
WHERE RW_PT_VOUCHER_NUMBER LIKE @PAYMENT_VOUCHER_NUMBER
    OR ML_PT_VOUCHER_NUMBER LIKE @PAYMENT_VOUCHER_NUMBER;

/* End of not working section */

/* This works fine */ 
SELECT REF_NUM
    ,CASE 
        WHEN RW_PT_VOUCHER_NUMBER = 'REVIEW_PAYMENT_VOUCHER_31'
            THEN 1
        WHEN ML_PT_VOUCHER_NUMBER = 'REVIEW_PAYMENT_VOUCHER_31'
            THEN 2
        END FEE_TYPE
FROM PROC_FEES_PYMTS
WHERE RW_PT_VOUCHER_NUMBER LIKE 'REVIEW_PAYMENT_VOUCHER_31'
    OR ML_PT_VOUCHER_NUMBER LIKE 'REVIEW_PAYMENT_VOUCHER_31';
```

Schema Information:

```
PROC_FEES_PYMTS -Table
REF_NUM - [varchar](15) NOT NULL
RW_PT_VOUCHER_NUMBER - [varchar](100) NULL
ML_PT_VOUCHER_NUMBER - [varchar](100) NULL
```

ideally this should return one row. But when using variable it does not return any row.

Is there any problem with this variable or am i doing any mistake in this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable length is the problem. it is not able to accommodate the input you are providing. Use some large number or MAX on the safe side. Also for like you should be using the % symbols or otherwise use equal(=) operator.

```
DECLARE @PAYMENT_VOUCHER_NUMBER VARCHAR(MAX) = 'REVIEW_PAYMENT_VOUCHER_31';

Select REF_NUM, 
    CASE 
        WHEN RW_PT_VOUCHER_NUMBER = @PAYMENT_VOUCHER_NUMBER Then 1 
        WHEN ML_PT_VOUCHER_NUMBER = @PAYMENT_VOUCHER_NUMBER Then 2 
    END FEE_TYPE  
From PROC_FEES_PYMTS 
Where 
    RW_PT_VOUCHER_NUMBER like '%' + @PAYMENT_VOUCHER_NUMBER + '%' OR ML_PT_VOUCHER_NUMBER like '%' + @PAYMENT_VOUCHER_NUMBER + '%'
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. You are accurate.

Answer (score 2):

When you load `'REVIEW_PAYMENT_VOUCHER_31'` into a `varchar(15)` you get

`'REVIEW_PAYMENT_'`

Your string is truncated to 15 characters. The first step to troubleshooting this would be to print the variable value

Use something like `VARCHAR(100)` instead